# Button for Install/Open PWA (standalone) Desktop only

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I want to achive feature for install/open button with PWA application my goal is:

- make button on my website for install PWA (i achive this)

```
 let installButton = document.getElementById('pwa-install');
 let prompt;
 window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     prompt = e;
 });

 installButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     prompt.prompt();
 })
```

- check if PWA is installed (if its possible)
- change button value for Open App and after click open the standalone application

my question is... there is any way for open prompt like chrome after user install PWA the icon change and chrome propose "Open Application"?

Im talking here only for desktop i dont use PWA for mobile devices.
I searched for something like this but only what i found is button for install and i wonder if it is even possible make button for open PWA as standalone app.

Thanks in advance for any help